# Calculating average per second in C

Tags: c, math, timer

I have an increasing integer value and want to find the average per second of that integer. I am aware that timers do not exist in C unless you do something specific and complicated [Im new to C] Is there a simpler way to do this? Preferably the value would reset when the calculation is made in order to not have such a large number in memory as this application will be running for a long time.

Comment: What kind of platform are you running this program on?

Comment: You asked for a "simpler" way to do it? Simpler than what? Show your current code, and we can suggest better ways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you will want to include `time.h`, and use some of its functions and structs (this is actually not a bad way of learning the basics of C). There is an explanation and a few examples [here](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/2.15.html).

If you need sub-second accuracy I suggest you use [`clock_gettime()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime), which will give you nanosecond resolution.

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

struct timespec diff(struct timespec start, struct timespec end);

int main()
{
    struct timespec time1, time2, timeDiff;
    int temp, i;

    // Get the start time
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &time1);

    // Do some work
    for (i = 0; i< 242000000; i++)
        temp+=temp;

    // Get the end time
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &time2);

    // Calculate the difference
    timeDiff = diff(time1,time2);

    printf("%d.%d\n", timeDiff.tv_sec, timeDiff.tv_nsec);
    return 0;
}

struct timespec diff(struct timespec start, struct timespec end)
{
    struct timespec temp;
    if ((end.tv_nsec-start.tv_nsec)<0) {
        temp.tv_sec = end.tv_sec-start.tv_sec-1;
        temp.tv_nsec = 1000000000+end.tv_nsec-start.tv_nsec;
    } else {
        temp.tv_sec = end.tv_sec-start.tv_sec;
        temp.tv_nsec = end.tv_nsec-start.tv_nsec;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

You will need to compile with something like:

```
gcc -o timetest timetest.c -lrt
```

The `-lrt` part of the command tells the C linker to link to the Realtime library, which contains the definition of `clock_gettime()`.

Comment: AMAZING! Thank you! I appreciate the fact that you explain the compiler flags too!

Comment: I have a question, how can I time a second, using the gettime method from the API until one second passes?

Comment: That might be tricky. You could either make repeated calls to `clock_gettime()` and stop after 1 sec, or you could `sleep()` for 1 sec. But if you want to continue processing things in the background and also have another process that keeps an eye on the time then you are going to have to use threads or some kind of event handler... and both of those options are 'specific and complicated', to use your term in the OP.

Comment: Well since I'm learning C and want to gain the most knowledge I looked into pthreads and managed to fit everything in a thread, I just need to figure out the arithmetic to get the X/sec. reading.

Comment: You don't need to take a reading exactly every second to get the operations/sec number. You can just take a time reading after, say 1000 operations, and do 1000/time.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use `gettimeofday()` to get a time value. You need to store one such reading, so that you can compare the most recent reading to the old and figure out the time between them. If you do this in seconds, you can divide your integer by that interval and get the average per second.